# Opengl acceleration problem in java 

Tags: java, opengl

Having problem with -Dsun.java2d.opengl=True.I managed to write a code in order to be able to set it to true/false when ever i want inside the program, but doesn't really work.i want to test the performance of java Graphics2D when opengl=true and when opengl=false.Does someone have any idea ?

Comment: It might just be me, but I don't get it: Do you have problems with switching or measuring the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=True` before you load up the GUI. So basically you can't switch between in middle of a running application and test the results like you want.

Though there might be a hidden way to force it to switch using reflection but nothing that I have come across yet.

Comment: Hmmm interesting answer.Yeah seems you are right. Don't really wanna mess with reflection yet.But it's a good idea.If I have time i see into it.